# Postfix smtpd - constant connect and disconnect in /var/log/mail.log

Tags: postfix-mta

I'm setting up a new server (Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS) with postfix v3.3.0.

I followed the standard deployment for postfix to send-only setup.

http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#null_client

```
1 /etc/postfix/main.cf:
2     myhostname = hostname.example.com
3     myorigin = $mydomain
4     relayhost = $mydomain
5     inet_interfaces = loopback-only
6     mydestination =
```

I can send emails from the server to an email and it works correctly.

However, when I do the listing of all port-25 listeners, I see the following:

```
lsof -Pi | grep :25
master    13753            root   13u  IPv4 274638      0t0  TCP localhost:25 (LISTEN)
master    13753            root   14u  IPv6 274639      0t0  TCP localhost:25 (LISTEN)
smtpd     13770         postfix    6u  IPv4 274638      0t0  TCP localhost:25 (LISTEN)
smtpd     13770         postfix    7u  IPv6 274639      0t0  TCP localhost:25 (LISTEN)
```

Based on digging on google, I found **smtpd** is used for receiving incoming emails however, I don't want to receive emails but just send only.

Also in the /var/log/mail.log, I see the following lines repeatedly. How do I stop this constant connect and disconnect from localhost?

```
Sep 27 07:15:52 mymachine postfix/smtpd[13780]: connect from localhost[::1]
Sep 27 07:15:52 mymachine postfix/smtpd[13780]: disconnect from localhost[::1] ehlo=1 quit=1 commands=2
Sep 27 07:17:52 mymachine postfix/smtpd[13787]: connect from localhost[::1]
Sep 27 07:17:53 mymachine postfix/smtpd[13787]: disconnect from localhost[::1] helo=1 quit=1 commands=2
Sep 27 07:17:53 mymachine postfix/smtpd[13787]: connect from localhost[::1]
Sep 27 07:17:53 mymachine postfix/smtpd[13787]: disconnect from localhost[::1] ehlo=1 quit=1 commands=2
Sep 27 07:19:53 mymachine postfix/smtpd[13790]: connect from localhost[::1]
Sep 27 07:19:53 mymachine postfix/smtpd[13790]: disconnect from localhost[::1] helo=1 quit=1 commands=2
Sep 27 07:19:53 mymachine postfix/smtpd[13790]: connect from localhost[::1]
Sep 27 07:19:53 mymachine postfix/smtpd[13790]: disconnect from localhost[::1] ehlo=1 quit=1 commands=2
```

Any ideas as what could be the issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

OK - After several digging on my environment, I found that there was monit ping every 2 minutes to check the status of postfix on port#25.  Since it is send-only setup where SMTPD daemon is disabled to listen on port#25.

I know it looks very trivial now but just wanted to mention to this post so when someone comes across it will save tons of frustrations.

Comment: hey! could you please elaborate? I'm trying to find out how to change duration of this timeout but so far no luck

Answer (score 0):

this is a correct health-check by monit (see linux man-page monit). To change the ping rate manually, open the file monitrc  (nano /etc/monit/monitrc) and change the line

`set daemon 120            # check services at 10-minute intervals`

to whatever ping-rate you want.